# How can I change the default directory for MathJax's configuration files?

Tags: javascript, assets, mathjax

I'm loading MathJax from my server, so that I can concatenate it with the rest of my JS assets to improve performance.  When I load the source file from my MathJax vendor directory, it works fine:

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({
    extensions: ["tex2jax.js"],
    jax: ["input/TeX", "output/HTML-CSS"],
    tex2jax: {
      inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ["\\(","\\)"] ],
      displayMath: [ ['$$','$$'], ["\\[","\\]"] ],
      processEscapes: true
    },
    "HTML-CSS": { availableFonts: ["TeX"] }
  });
</script>
<script src="http://example.com/assets-raw/vendor/MathJax/MathJax.js" ></script>
```

However, when I minify/concatenate `MathJax.js` with the rest of my assets, the combined JS file is now found in a completely separate directory:

```
<script src="http://example.com/assets/js/minified.js" ></script>
```

Unfortunately when I do this, MathJax can no longer find `config.js`, `tex2jax.js`, or any of its other dependencies.  The problem seems to be that MathJax has a "default directory" where it expects to find these files, and this default is a relative directory.

Looking at [MathJax's documentation](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/options/hub.html), they say things like

> The default directory is `MathJax/extensions/`

But they do not tell you how to override this default.  Is this possible through MathJax's configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is an undocumented configuration setting, `root`, that can be used to set the root path in the `Config` options.  For example:

```
root: 'http://example.com/assets-raw/vendor/MathJax'
```

Comment: Looks like this is not working anymore :| Tried with v2.6.x through v2.7.x